# Are there softwares or forums which allow you to publish apps to app store on shared basis?

Tags: iphone-app, apple

Given that Apple charges hefty developer fee of $99/yr. Are there softwares, forums by which mutiple developers can collaborate to publish their app via same developer account and thus save on the large developer fee which apple charges.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want-  I think, For sharing just the app, (making it available for download) then [github.com](https://github.com/) will suffice.

Support for payment for the app (one-off/subscription), support for in-app-purchases, worldwide distribution, malware checking, monitoring and reporting, support for a Platform API and many more . These are huge topics and  you should clarify in your question what you need.

For in-house team support you should look for a new buzzword: "Internal developer platform" products. (I cannot recommend anything here, only know that some products exist)

Comment: I already have option to download dmg from my website/github etc. To increase traction I am looking for an additional option that it get downloads from appstore searches as well. For that I need a paid apple developer account. I was looking if there are alternative like say bunch of people are sharing the same account and hence sharing the $100 fee too.

Comment: Apple has provision to [add team members](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-your-team/invite-team-members/). I am not sure that adding team members is free. I guess their pricing is per member right ?

Comment: I am confused,  are individual developer accounts free ? so individual developer account with in app purchase using 3rd party payment system like stripe etc pays nothing to apple  ?

Comment: I wanted to provided a comment but my text was too long for that. 
And sorry - I don't know the terms of Service of the Apple Developer programm and the App Store.

Comment: I was wrong there is nothing free. moreover for safari there is no 2nd option.

Comment: For macOS apps even though you can host the dmg externally but that option not only deprives you of appstore traffic but also restricts you at security level. Your users have to open security settings on mac and explicitly unblock the 3rd party app after installing it (https://imgur.com/HNwH3X7), which very few know how to do and hence there is further drop in users even after installing.